# Regex > get YouTube Playlist ID?

Tags: regex, youtube

Hi I am trying to get the playlist ID of a youtube url. The code below is not solid since the id 'PLcfQmtiAG0X-fmM85dPlql5wfYbmFumzQ' will not be extracted properly. It only returns 'PLcfQmtiAG0X'. Can someone help me?

```
var reg = new RegExp("[&?]list=([a-z0-9_]+)","i");
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcfQmtiAG0X-fmM85dPlql5wfYbmFumzQ';
var match = reg.exec(url);
return match[1];
```

Comment: Use `var reg = /[&?]list=([^&]+)/i;`

Comment: You have to include `-` in your character class `[a-z0-9_-]+`

Comment: Thank you it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do a fair amount of regex work with URLs.  Usually you'll want to use a parser but sometimes that is not an option.  So to gather params I like to use a negative character class like this

```
/[&?]list=([^&]+)/i
```

The [&?] will mean that you won't match &split=123 since it has to start with a & or ?

The [^&]+ is the real magic, it means capture all the non & which is the value you are going for.  If you want to play around, this site is pretty good:

https://regex101.com/